# Does SSL perform automatic renegotiation

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I have a client server application written in c++ using SSL 1.0.1n for socket communication. I am trying to prevent renegotiation (it's a requirement). Nowhere in my code do I initiate a renegotiation. 
   I see openssl has a BIO_set_ssl_renegotiate_bytes and BIO_set_ssl_renegotiate_timeout that allows you to set up automatic renegotiation after a certain number of bytes are read or a timeout. 
   My question is if I don't set a value for either one of these, do they have a default value where SSL will still initiate a renegotiate automatically? I am having trouble figuring out what causes a renegotiation if not done in code.

Comment: You *could* always read the OpenSSL source code to get your answer...

Comment: You don't like increased security?

Comment: I have done as you suggested and it appears that these two values are only set through calls to the 2 functions above. So I conclude from that that no automatic renegotiation is done  without setting the bytes or the timeout. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

*I am trying to prevent renegotiation (it's a requirement)*

Hopefully that requirement isn't in response to [CVE-2009-3555](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2009-3555).    That was fixed in [OpenSSL 0.9.8k in Nov 2009](http://openssl.cs.utah.edu/news/openssl-0.9.8-notes.html).  TLSv1.1 and later protocols have never been subject to that vulnerability.

However, you can still [set the `SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION` option via `SSL_CTX_set_options()` or `SSL_set_options`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_CTX_set_options.html):

> **SSL_CTX_set_options**
>
> **NAME**
>
> SSL_CTX_set_options, SSL_set_options, SSL_CTX_clear_options,
>   SSL_clear_options, SSL_CTX_get_options, SSL_get_options,
>   SSL_get_secure_renegotiation_support - manipulate SSL options
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>  #include <openssl/ssl.h>
>
>  long SSL_CTX_set_options(SSL_CTX *ctx, long options);
>  long SSL_set_options(SSL *ssl, long options);
>
>  long SSL_CTX_clear_options(SSL_CTX *ctx, long options);
>  long SSL_clear_options(SSL *ssl, long options);
>
>  long SSL_CTX_get_options(SSL_CTX *ctx);
>  long SSL_get_options(SSL *ssl);
>
>  long SSL_get_secure_renegotiation_support(SSL *ssl);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> SSL_CTX_set_options() adds the options set via bitmask in options to
>   ctx. Options already set before are not cleared!
>
> SSL_set_options() adds the options set via bitmask in options to ssl.
>   Options already set before are not cleared!
>
> SSL_CTX_clear_options() clears the options set via bitmask in options
>   to ctx.
>
> SSL_clear_options() clears the options set via bitmask in options to
>   ssl.
>
> SSL_CTX_get_options() returns the options set for ctx.
>
> SSL_get_options() returns the options set for ssl.
>
> SSL_get_secure_renegotiation_support() indicates whether the peer
>   supports secure renegotiation. Note, this is implemented via a macro.
>   NOTES
>
> The behaviour of the SSL library can be changed by setting several
>   options. The options are coded as bitmasks and can be combined by a
>   bitwise or operation (|).
>
> SSL_CTX_set_options() and SSL_set_options() affect the (external)
>   protocol behaviour of the SSL library. The (internal) behaviour of the
>   API can be changed by using the similar SSL_CTX_set_mode and
>   SSL_set_mode() functions.
>
> During a handshake, the option settings of the SSL object are used.
>   When a new SSL object is created from a context using SSL_new(), the
>   current option setting is copied. Changes to ctx do not affect already
>   created SSL objects. SSL_clear() does not affect the settings.
>
> ...
>
> The following **modifying** options are available:
>
> ...
>
> SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION
>
> Disable all renegotiation in TLSv1.2 and earlier. Do not send
>   HelloRequest messages, and ignore renegotiation requests via
>   ClientHello.
>
> **SECURE RENEGOTIATION**
>
> ...

Note that the page has a "SECURE RENEGOTIAION" section.  Read it.

Then, you really need to review your requirements.  There's a good chance they're a decade out-of-date.  By having you spend time and effort on problems **that were fixed a decade ago**, you're not spending time and effort fixing addressing current issues.

Comment: I have downloaded several versions of the source and this option only appears starting in 1.1.1. I'm using 1.0.1n

Comment: @user3621099 Upgrading from 1.0.1 to 1.1.1 shouldn't be that hard.  The major differences are that many structures have become opaque, so where in the earlier version you'd have to dig into the data fields yourself to get to certain things like certificate extensions, 1.1.1 now provides `..._get0_...()` functions to retrieve the same fields.